# How to convert this query in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have got this piece of snippet from: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9ec7e/4/0

What it does is it gets all the data from the table, All duplicate rows will be counted as 1 and lastly get only the latest data that ID/Item.

```
SELECT
        p.*
    FROM
        (
          -- For every product_id, find maximum created_at time
          SELECT
              product_id, max(created_at) AS created_at
          FROM 
              purchases
          GROUP BY
              product_id
         ) AS mx 
         -- JOIN to the whole table
         JOIN purchases p ON
              mx.product_id = p.product_id AND mx.created_at = p.created_at
    ORDER BY
         product_id ;
```

Here's the picture of the result from the snippet above.
Picture of the result (image):
[image: Picture of the result (image)]

The real question is, how can I make it work with CodeIgniter3 query?
Or How can I do this query in CodeIgniter3.

I tried using **$this->db->query();** but no luck.
Here's the image of my take using the snippet above and changed the table name, column. Result of my take (image):
[image: Result of my take (image)]

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of your code or error messages and do not link to external sources. Screenshots are hard to read on mobile devices, they cannot be searched and none of us can copy, paste and run 

an image, links can get obsolete. Code should be included as text in the question itself. For more on this see 
[**Why may I not upload images of code**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) 
on SO when asking a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT p.* FROM (SELECT product_id, max(created_at) AS created_at FROM purchases GROUP BYproduct_id) AS mx 
     JOIN purchases p ON mx.product_id = p.product_id AND mx.created_at = p.created_at ORDER BY product_id");

return $query->result();
```

hope this helped

Comment: Hi sir, it worked! lol. i just changed result_array() to result() 'coz i want it to be an object. Thanks a lot.

Comment: urwel sir,  solved.